# Xamarin IOS login move to another page

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin IOS. I can't find a solution on how to go to another page after login. Like in Android. Any advice?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/hello-ios-multiscreen/hello-ios-multiscreen-deepdive

Comment: @Jason Thank you! This have been helpful to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter whether your loginPage is contained inside storyboard or not ,the best way is changing `Window.RootViewController` in `AppDelegate` after login.

#### Inside LoginPage

```
if (login)
{
    AppDelegate app = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
    app.changeOtherPage();
}
```

#### Inside AppDelegate

```
public void changeOtherPage ()
{
    //if the page is contained in storyboard
    UIStoryboard sb = UIStoryboard.FromName("SBName",null);
    OtherPage callHistory = sb.InstantiateViewController("OtherPage") as OtherPage;
    Window.RootViewController = callHistory;

    //if the page is not contained in storyboard
    Window.RootViewController = new OtherPage();
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you!